# MySQL : Inserting data twice

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I wrote a function to insert the data, it worked fine up to the previous project, but now i am facing issue, the problem is data is inserting two times. I tried to print the query, every thing is fine, and there are no loops. If i execute the query from `phpmyadmin` then it works fine.

Code is as below:

```
<?php 
function insert($table,$headers,$data)
{
    global $conn;

    debug_print_backtrace();
    $values = "'".implode("','",$data)."'";

    $sql = "insert into ".$table."(".implode(",",$headers).") values(".$values.")";

echo $sql;
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($res)
        return true;
    else
        return mysql_error();
}


include('controller.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
global $conn;
$email = check_email($_POST['email']);

$sub = explode(",", $_POST['suburb']);
$to = get("admin",'0');


//$fileName = implode(",", $fileName);

$headers = array('SM_ID','password','SM_key','Active','Block','SM_EID','C_ID','SM_Name','Email_ID','Mobile','Address','Suburb','PIN','State','Profile_Pic','Date');



$_SESSION['key'] = $key;

$rand = mt_rand(0, 32);
//$password = md5($rand.time());
$length = 10;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $password = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $password .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
//echo $password;


$check_eid = get_max('service_manager','SM_EID');
var_dump($check_eid);
/*$check_eid = $check_eid['0']['SM_EID'];//*/
$check_eid = explode("_", $check_eid);
//var_dump($check_eid['1']);
if(!$check_eid['1'])
$sm_eid = 100;
else
$sm_eid  = $check_eid['1']+1;
$sm_eid = "SM_".$sm_eid;


//echo $sm_eid;
$key = md5($sm_eid.$_POST['email']);

$data = array('',md5($password),$key,'1','0',$sm_eid,$_POST['zone'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone'],mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['address']),$sub['0'],$sub['1'],$_POST['state'],$_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"],date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time()));

$insert = insert('service_manager',$headers,$data);

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query()` but you use `return mysql_error();`?

Comment: problem is with inserting data, not with the error

Comment: which is why it was a comment, not an answer. if you have an error, you won't get it unless you change to `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: How is your form posted? Is it possible that it is done with ajax/javascript, which could be calling it twice, either directly, or indirectly (ie. by ajax but without `preventDefault()` causing the form to post naturally as well)

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for you comment.Yes i called an ajax file to check whether the email id is exists or not and that is only the problem.solved it :)